# Win 7 64-bit user profile login problem

Tags: windows-7

My newly clean installed Win 7 64 system has a developed a very peculiar user profile login problem. When logging on from starting the system, I can login to a user profile no problem. It is when I log out of that profile and attempt to login to another profile that the fun starts. As soon as the profile login screen appears, the password dialog box immediately fills itself in. If I delete it and attempt to type in the correct password, the box immediately fills itself in again. It seems to be using a single letter, such as 'c', 'u', 'g' which I suspect may be related to windows looking for the drive that the password reset information is on, but I'm not sure. Very bizarre behaviour. I can only get out of it by rebooting, which allows me to login properly. It doesn't do this all the time but does do it frequently. Any ideas how it may be cured?

Comment: Silly question, but have you checked whether any keys on the keyboard are sticking?

Comment: No. It's a brand new Microsoft keyboard. There is nothing wrong with it. I plugged in my old HP keyboard and it didn't make any difference. It's a software glitch issue without a doubt, but one that doesn't make itself readily apparent.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like you have a keyboard and/or mouse driver issue going on. If you have any "drivers" for your keyboard and/or mouse then I would suggest uninstalling them. Don't worry, you should still be able to use your keyboard and mouse but you probably won't have any extra functions like certain hot keys or even certain buttons on your mouse might no longer work - but you should at least still be able to use them. Of course, reinstalling drivers for a mouse and/or keyboard theoretically will enable those extra abilities but you might also have that weird problem again too. (Have you obtained the latest drivers?!)

Aside from that, you might also look into any other input devices you may have hooked up to your computer like scanners, joysticks, and/or possibly even old dial-up modems. And that's just for starts. The list of input or even output devices is pretty long but reducing your computer to it's most basic elements with just a basic keyboard and basic mouse is where I'd at least begin the troubleshooting process. And if your keyboard/mouse are USB devices you might also look into your BIOS settings too (again, that's a bit too borad a topic to go into here).

Hope that helps a little, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

No solution, but for some advice on debugging see: [Troubleshooting the Windows logon process](http://www.parmiter.com/microsoft/windows-2003/2008/08/RP322).

This uses information from this Microsoft Support article :
[How to enable user environment debug logging in retail builds of Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/221833)

If this gets you any useful information, please post it.

You can also try to check your system using [sfc /scannow](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/1538-sfc-scannow-command-system-file-checker.html).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll try the troubleshooting links. I have used sfc and it reports no problems ditto chkdsk. I think I'll start by deleting all the passwords and resetting them.

Answer (score 0):

**1) Try Repairing windows 7 installation**

For more information regarding repairing Win7 ,

go here http://www.nirmaltv.com/2009/12/17/how-to-repair-windows-7-installation/
or go here http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/681-startup-repair.html

**2) Try deleting that account and creating a new one**

**3) Try removing password for that account and then putting it again**

**4) Scan for any type of winlogin virus**

Comment: Hi. Done all that except deleting account and creating a new one. All the diagnostics I've used find no issues. If I change profiles while in safe mode, no problem. If I switch user in normal mode, no problem. If I log off in normal mode and then log on to another profile, problem! This is very weird. However, I've got round it by logging in as administrator in safe mode and deleting all passwords. Now it works just fine. I'll do the delete profile when I have the time. This is a work machine so too much hassle at present.

Comment: Glad you found a work around, inform me when u try the rest